# Is there a statistically best place to be in a line to choose lowest number from a pool?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

Here's the situation:
There is a line of 500 people. Each will be given a random number from 1 to 500.

I want to find out if there is a best place to be a line to get the best odds at getting a low number.

We can define the numbers as follows 1-100 = best, 101-200 = good, 201-500= bad.

So here's what I have: the first person has 100/500 to get best 100/500 to get good and 300/500 to get bad numbers. 2nd person has 99/499 or 100/499 to get both best and good numbers and 299/499 or 299/500 to get bad numbers.

Is this even right? There must be a simpler way and from what I've looking into hypergeometric random distribution might be what I need. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Think about it as a shuffled deck of cards.  What are your chances of picking a given card from the top of the deck?  Does it matter if you draw from the middle instead?

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, no.

We can say with certainty that the first person has a 20% chance of getting in the "best" category, a 20% chance of getting in the "good" category, and a 60% chance of getting in the "bad" category.

The second person's numbers depend on the first person's number - for example, if the first person is in the "best" category, then there is a higher chance that the second person is in the "good" or "bad" categories.  However, since we don't know what the first person got, we can't say anything about the second person's chances.

As another example, there is only one number left after the first 499 have been given out... so the person who is last in line must automatically get that number, whatever it is.  But since all numbers occur equally, we can't say anything about what number that last person gets.

As a result, there is no benefit to getting a certain spot in line.